# Boost.MultiArray as a member of a class: resize and copy assertion crash

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, boost

To show the problem, let suppose you have a class called basic_ma and has a member which is a MultiArray (**MA**). Also suppose that in the constructor (or in a method) you have some computations in a temporary **MA** (called `tmp` here) and you want to copy the contents of `tmp` to `ma` (this behavior is desired, i would like to have at the same time `tmp` and `ma`).

```
// A class with a MultiArray member
class basic_ma {
public:
  basic_ma() { }

  // initialize ma
  basic_ma(size_t x, size_t y) {
    // I would like to compute in tmp and then copy to member ma
    array2d tmp(boost::extents[x][y]);
    // dummy stuff, some serious calculation in real life
    for(size_t i=0; i<tmp.shape()[0]; ++i) {
      for(size_t j=0; j<tmp.shape()[1]; ++j) {
        tmp[i][j] = (i+1.0)*(j+1.0);
      }
    }
    ma.resize(boost::extents[tmp.shape()[0]][tmp.shape()[1]]);
    ma = tmp;
    // Alternative function to copy
    //copy_ma(tmp, ma);
    } 

  void show() {
    cout << endl << "> Show ma" << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ma.shape()[0]; ++i) {
      cout << "> ";
      for(size_t j = 0; j < ma.shape()[1]; ++j) {
        cout << ma[i][j] << '\t';
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
private:
  array2d ma;// MultiArray member
};
```

Now consider another class which member is the previous class.

```
// Another class has several (possibly a vector of) basic_ma's
class group_ma {
public:
  group_ma() { }
  // constructs basic_ma's
  group_ma(size_t x, size_t y) {
    bma1 = basic_ma(x, y);
    bma1.show();
    bma2 = basic_ma(y, x);
    bma2.show();
  }
private:
  basic_ma bma1;
  basic_ma bma2;
};
```

Then an assertion problem occurs when I instantiate the `group_ma` using the constructor with two parameters:

```
a.out: /usr/include/boost/multi_array/multi_array_ref.hpp:484: boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>& boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::operator=(const ConstMultiArray&) [with ConstMultiArray = boost::multi_array<double, 2ul>; T = double; long unsigned int NumDims = 2ul]: Assertion `std::equal(other.shape(),other.shape()+this->num_dimensions(), this->shape())' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  basic_ma bma(3,5);// OK compile and run
  bma.show();// OK compile and run

  group_ma gma1;// OK compile and run

  gma1 = group_ma(3, 3);// Compile but assertion error when running

  group_ma gma2(4, 2);// Compile but assertion error when running

  unique_ptr<group_ma> gma_ptr = unique_ptr<group_ma>(new group_ma(5, 6));
  // Compile but assertion error when running

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc version 6.2.1`:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=gnu++11 -pedantic -Wall
```

The `basic_ma` works fine, the problem occurs when using `group_ma`.
I also tried another function to copy the **MA**'s with the same result:

```
// copy Boost.MultiArray source to dest
void copy_ma(const array2d source, array2d& dest) {
  vector<size_t> grid;
  const size_t* shape = source.shape();
  grid.assign(shape, shape+source.num_dimensions());
  dest.resize(grid);
  for(size_t i=0; i<source.shape()[0]; ++i) {
    for(size_t j=0; j<source.shape()[1]; ++j) {
      dest[i][j] = source[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

I do not see what i'm doing wrong.
Using the `-DNDEBUG` flag raises a memory error: `malloc(): memory corruption (fast)`

The whole code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> array2d;

// A class with a MultiArray member
class basic_ma {
public:
  basic_ma() { }
  // initialize ma
  basic_ma(size_t x, size_t y) {
    // I would like to compute in tmp and the copy to member ma
    array2d tmp(boost::extents[x][y]);
    // dummy stuff
    for(size_t i=0; i<tmp.shape()[0]; ++i) {
      for(size_t j=0; j<tmp.shape()[1]; ++j) {
        tmp[i][j] = (i+1.0)*(j+1.0);
      }
    }
    ma.resize(boost::extents[tmp.shape()[0]][tmp.shape()[1]]);
    ma = tmp;
    // Alternative function to copy
//     copy_ma(tmp, ma);
  }
  void show() {
    cout << endl << "> Show ma" << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ma.shape()[0]; ++i) {
        cout << "> ";
        for(size_t j = 0; j < ma.shape()[1]; ++j) {
          cout << ma[i][j] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
private:
  array2d ma;// MultiArray member
};


// copy Boost.MultiArray source to dest
void copy_ma(const array2d source, array2d& dest) {
  vector<size_t> grid;
  const size_t* shape = source.shape();
  grid.assign(shape, shape+source.num_dimensions());
  dest.resize(grid);
  for(size_t i=0; i<source.shape()[0]; ++i) {
    for(size_t j=0; j<source.shape()[1]; ++j) {
      dest[i][j] = source[i][j];
    }
  }
}

// Another class will have several (possibly a vector of) basic_ma's
class group_ma {
public:
  group_ma() { }
  // constructs basic_ma's
  group_ma(size_t x, size_t y) {
    bma1 = basic_ma(x, y);
    bma1.show();
    bma2 = basic_ma(y, x);
    bma2.show();
  }
private:
  basic_ma bma1;
  basic_ma bma2;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  basic_ma bma(3,5);// OK compile and run
  bma.show();// OK compile and run

  group_ma gma1;// OK compile and run

  gma1 = group_ma(3, 3);// Compile but assertion error when running

  group_ma gma2(4, 2);// Compile but assertion error when running

  unique_ptr<group_ma> gma_ptr = unique_ptr<group_ma>(new group_ma(5, 6));
  // Compile but assertion error when running

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that the arrays are not the same size during assignment. There are several ways to fix it. In the group_ma use the constructor:

```
group_ma(size_t x, size_t y)
    :bma1( x, y )
    ,bma2( y, x )
{
    //bma1 = basic_ma(x, y);
    bma1.show();
    //bma2 = basic_ma(y, x);
    bma2.show();
}
```

the default constructor did not give you a 3x3. Boost docs talk about resizing a multi_array and you could do that if you must assign. But with the caveat that the dimentions remain the same.

Adding the member to `basic_ma`

```
void resize(size_t x, size_t y )
{
    ma.resize( boost::extents[x][y] );
}
```

then:

```
basic_ma not_initialized;
not_initialized.resize( 3, 3 );
basic_ma bma(3,3);
bma.show();
not_initialized= bma; // now this works
not_initialized.show( );
```

Another thought, you could do the resize in your own assignment operator...

So if you want the `basic_ma` to remain private. make `group_ma` a friend of `basic_ma`. Then you can add this to `group_ma`

```
void operator = ( group_ma& source )
{
    bma1.resize( source.bma1.ma.shape( )[ 0 ], source.bma1.ma.shape( )[ 1 ] );
    bma2.resize( source.bma2.ma.shape( )[ 0 ], source.bma2.ma.shape( )[ 1 ] );
    bma1= source.bma1;
    bma2= source.bma2;
}
```

Then this works:

```
group_ma gma1;
gma1 = group_ma(3, 3);
group_ma gma2(4, 2);
gma1= gma2;
```

There may be better ways, I don't know as I haven't looked. But I think this may suit you.

And yet another thought and better if you have different kinds of groups. Do the resize in an assignment operator of `basic_ma`. Then in the group assignment you only need:

```
void operator = ( group_ma& source )
{
    bma1= source.bma1;
    bma2= source.bma2;
}
```

Comment: It works! As you pointed `bma1 = basic_ma(x, y);` doesn't work. Another workaround is to implement the move assignment operator `basic_ma& operator=(const basic_ma&& other_bma)`. For my specific application I think that it suits better because I cannot call directly the constructor of `basic_ma`. But still not 100% sure.